# Canvas apagar texto correto

Tags: javascript, canvas

Eu ando em pesquisas e não há maneira de fazer isto trabalhar, a primeira tentativa funciona bem, mas a segunda já não, ou seja, não apaga o texto que lá estava e o substitui pelo novo (no campo correspondente), presumo que a minha função `clearRect()` não esteja a levar os argumentos corretos:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
canvas.style.background = 'red';
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
$('.define').on('click', function() {
  var txt = $($(this).data('target')).val();
  var txt_color = $(this).data('colortext');
  var txt_size = $(this).data('fontsize');
  var x = $(this).data('x');
  var y = $(this).data('y');
  ctx.font = txt_size+ " Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = txt_color;
  ctx.clearRect(x, y, canvas.width, ctx.measureText(txt).height);
  ctx.fillText(txt, x, y);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas><br>
<input id="title"><br>
<button class="define" data-target="#title" data-colortext="black" data-fontsize="30px" data-x="10" data-y="50">Definir Titulo</button><br><br>
<input id="text"><br>
<button class="define" data-target="#text" data-colortext="blue" data-fontsize="20px" data-x="10" data-y="80">Definir Texto</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testa assim:

```
    ctx.clearRect(x, y, canvas.width, -parseInt(txt_size, 10));
```

O problema aqui é saber a altura do texto dentro do canvas e [isso não é muito fácil](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1134586/2256325).

Como estás a usar pixeis podes usar o `txt_size` qu deverá ser a altura do texto e só precisas de inverter uma vez que o ponto de partida do y é na base do texto e queremos limpar para cima.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
canvas.style.background = 'red';
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
$('.define').on('click', function() {
    var txt = $($(this).data('target')).val();
    var txt_color = $(this).data('colortext');
    var txt_size = $(this).data('fontsize');
    var x = $(this).data('x');
    var y = $(this).data('y');
    ctx.font = txt_size + " Arial";
    ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
    ctx.fillStyle = txt_color;
    ctx.clearRect(x, y, canvas.width, -parseInt(txt_size, 10));
    ctx.fillText(txt, x, y);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas><br>
<input id="title"><br>
<button class="define" data-target="#title" data-colortext="black" data-fontsize="30px" data-x="10" data-y="50">Definir Titulo</button><br><br>
<input id="text"><br>
<button class="define" data-target="#text" data-colortext="blue" data-fontsize="20px" data-x="10" data-y="80">Definir Texto</button>
```

Comment: Eu sabia que podia contar contigo, já estava a adivinhavar que havias de ser tu a resolver. Mas sim, tens razão, com esse ajuste para as letras (p, g, etcc....) ficava perfeito. Obagdo Sergio

Comment: @Miguel dá uma olhada agora

Comment: Perfeito Sergio, não mexe mais senão estraga lol. Obagdo

Comment: Só uma pergunta, `ctx.measureText(txt).height` porque não funciona?

Answer (score 3):

Presumo que usando o método [`filterText()`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/canvas_filltext.asp) já funcionaria para este caso, substituindo o texto antigo por um novo. Basta inserir o código desta forma: `ctx.fillText(txt, 15, canvas.height / 2 + 35)`. Veja abaixo como ficaria:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
canvas.style.background = 'red';
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
$('.define').on('click', function() {
  var txt = $($(this).data('target')).val();
  var txt_color = $(this).data('colortext');
  var txt_size = $(this).data('fontsize');
  var x = $(this).data('x');
  var y = $(this).data('y');
  ctx.font = txt_size+ " Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = txt_color;
  ctx.clearRect(x, y, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillText(txt, 15, canvas.height / 2 + 35);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas><br>
<input id="title"><br>
<button class="define" data-target="#title" data-colortext="black" data-fontsize="30px" data-x="10" data-y="50">Definir Titulo</button><br><br>
<input id="text"><br>
<button class="define" data-target="#text" data-colortext="blue" data-fontsize="20px" data-x="10" data-y="80">Definir Texto</button>
```

Veja mais [na documentação sobre HTML5 Canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp).

Comment: Obrigado, acho que é o caminho certo, mas há um problema. Eu só quero que atue no campo correspondente, ou seja, se for o texto ele apaga e reescreve só o texto, desta maneira tu estás a apagar os dois, assim também tinha conseguido há pouco

Comment: @Miguel vamos resolver o problema juntos então. Vou analisar! Você quer permanecer cada um em suas devidas localizações certo?

Comment: Exato Ack, é isso mesmo... O facto de alterar um não deve interferir com o outro